# Open port 1194 for openvpn service

Tags: centos, firewall, openvpn, port

I am looking to open the openvpn service on my CentOS VM. When I run `nmap -sU localhost -p 1194`, the following is output:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-01-08 13:23 GMT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000039s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1194/udp closed openvpn

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

How would I open this? I have already run the command sudo `/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT` and it doesn't work.

When I run `netstat -an|grep 1194`, nothing appears.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `proto udp` in the relevant server `.conf` file, and that openvpn is running?  What does `netstat -an|grep 1194` say?  (Please paste any output into your *question*.)

Comment: I have pasted this into the question

Comment: OK, the evidence is strong that, if OpenVPN is running, it's not running on the normal port.  What makes you think it's running *at all*?

Answer (score 1):

Having openvpn bind to localhost:1194 doesn't really make much sense unless you're doing something you haven't told us about, as it's not like you can connect to it from anywhere useful but still...

Unless you have specified otherwise by using the `local` directive then the documentation suggests that it should bind to all available IP addresses so you could try nmaping the others.

Alternatively you can use `ps` to see if you have any openvpn processes running, if not check your logs after/during an attempt to start them (service openvpn start | systemctl start openvpn).

If your processes are running then check what interfaces they are listening on,

`netstat -tulp | grep openvpn`

...